# How to disable the "guard" feature in facebook react when working with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to get the native javascript error and not their (react's) "guarded" error.

What is "guard": https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/9270d3d56ea3b196acc099409a38e6c07b191e46/src/vendor/stubs/ReactErrorUtils.js

https://github.com/facebook/react/search?q=guard&ref=cmdform

As you can see errors like `Object [object Object] has no method 'map'.` are hard to debug. (http://www.andrewgreig.com/637/)

For example I get this error:

```
undefined.__closeView: undefined is not a function react.js:7276
guarded react.js:7276
boundMethod react.js:4920
```

From this I cannot even know where to start to find what is undefined.

Comment: "*“guard” in facebook react*"? What exactly are you talking about? Is this a webpage you're working on? A plugin?
We need more info before we can help.

Comment: when a click is made is ran the "select" method. This fires and event and is catched by another part of the app. Here the app throws an error. I'm using React.createClass

Comment: I really don't understand why there are so many negative votes?? if someone worked with react should know that there is a guard feature that wrapps the original javascript error...

Comment: I do @Totty :) but it would be nice to better understand what this guard method is bothering you and what you mean by "pure javascript". Has it something to do with functional purity?

Comment: You can see here what is the guard I've been talking: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/9270d3d56ea3b196acc099409a38e6c07b191e46/src/vendor/stubs/ReactErrorUtils.js . When an error happens in the script it will not be thrown immediately, but will be catched by the "guard" and the "guard" will re-throw the error again. By doing that makes my life a lot harder to understand where the problem is. I prefer the javascript pure errors, without being catched.

Answer (score 0):

As you gave the guard implementation:

```
var ReactErrorUtils = {
  /**
   * Creates a guarded version of a function. This is supposed to make debugging
   * of event handlers easier. This implementation provides only basic error
   * logging and re-throws the error.
   *
   * @param {function} func Function to be executed
   * @param {string} name The name of the guard
   * @return {function}
   */
  guard: function(func, name) {
    if (__DEV__) {
      return function guarded() {
        try {
          return func.apply(this, arguments);
        } catch(ex) {
          console.error(name + ': ' + ex.message);
          throw ex;
        }
      };
    } else {
      return func;
    }
  }
};
```

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/9270d3d56ea3b196acc099409a38e6c07b191e46/src/vendor/stubs/ReactErrorUtils.js

Maybe you can try to not be in `__DEV__` mode, or open an issue to support an easy way to disable it.